# Excalibur sword probability

Tags: probability

Here is a story of King Arthur who's in a battlefield with his $7$ soldiers. He left his sword Excalibur to one of his soldier, also the other $6$ soldiers got an identical looking sword (for deceiving).

It happens that they encountered a dragon who can only be killed by using the Excalibur sword, however in a rush Arthur doesn't have time to check which is the real sword, and since he can only carry two swords he picks randomly two sword from his soldiers.

This is quite a special dragon who will break the sword if it's a fake and nothing will happen, and there is only a $90\%$ probability that he'll be killed if Arthur uses the Excalibur.

What is the probability that the dragon will be killed if Arthur goes in alone?

My idea is first to find the probability that Arthur will pick the Excalibur among those swords or if he doesn't pick it. Then to see what will happen with them.

Since he must carry two swords, and only one is real, one of the swords must be a fake so this leaves two cases picking the right one, and picking a fake one.

$$P(\text{picking Excalibur}\ \& \ a fake)=\frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{6}{1}}{\binom{7}{2}}=\frac{4}{7}$$
$$P(\text{picking two fakes})=\frac{\binom{2}{0}\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{7}{2}}=\frac{5}{7}$$
And now I am struggling to finalize. But since the probability of killing if it's a fake is $0$ we can ignore that, right?
$$P(\text{killing the dragon})=P(\text{chance of killing the dragon}\  \cap\ \text{having excalibur})=\frac{9}{10}\cdot \frac47 $$ Is that it? Something seems wrong to me since the probability is kinda high and I think I am missing something obvious.

---

Edit: Further problem that was suggested in comments by JMoravitz.

What is the probability of killing the dragon if the fake sword got a probability of killing of $\frac{2}{10}$?

Here is my thinking. Now using the correct version we have:
$$P(\text{picking Excalibur}\ \& \ a fake)=\frac{\binom{\color{red}{1}}{1}\binom{6}{1}}{\binom{7}{2}}=\frac{2}{7}$$
$$P(\text{picking two fakes})=\frac{\binom{\color{red} 1}{0}\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{7}{2}}=\frac{5}{7}$$
$$P(\text{killing the dragon})=P(\text{chance of killing the dragon}\  \cap\ \text{having excalibur})$$$$+P(\text{chance of killing the dragon}\  \cap\ \text{not having excalibur})=\frac{9}{10}\cdot \frac27 +\frac{2}{10}\cdot \frac57=\frac{28}{70}=\frac25$$

---

Given the dragon is successfully slain, what is the probability that Arthur is actually holding the Excalibur?

$$P(\text{Excalibur/slain})=\frac{P(\text{Excalibur/slain})P(\text{Excalibur})}{P(\text{slain})}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{9}{10}\cdot \frac{2}{7}}{\frac{9}{10}\frac{2}{7}+\frac{2}{10}\frac{5}{7}}=\frac{18}{28}=\frac{9}{14}$$
Where for $P(\text{slain})$ I have used the probability of killing with Excalibur plus the probability of killing with a fake one.

Can anyone confirm if I proceeded correctly?

Comment: The rules are not clear.  Arthur has two swords.  Can he try them both on the dragon or can he only try one?  If the latter, then this is exactly the same as if he chose one sword to begin with.

Comment: Yes, he can try them both, but if it's the real one he only needs one try, right?

Comment: He can carry 2 Excaliburs? I mean, Are there 2 excaliburs?

Comment: The point is that he has two tries to pick the right one.  That is critical.  Given that he is choosing $2$ out of $7$, the probability that he chooses the right one is $\frac 27$.

Comment: Yes, he has two tries.// Excalibur is unique (only a real one), but there are $6$ identical looking fake swords looking like the real one.

Comment: Your computations are incompatible.  Clearly the probability that he chooses two fakes + the probability he chooses one fake and the real one must be $1$.

Comment: Hint:  the factor $\binom 21$ doesn't belong there.

Comment: Why not? I directly applied the hypergeometric distribution, and since there are  two picks and only a real sword, we have $\binom{2}{1}$. Where is the flaw in my thinking?

Comment: @Pyckaz King arthur can choose his sword at first time with probability $\frac17$. Or he can choose his sword at the second time, but not at the first time. The probability is $\frac67\cdot \frac16=\frac17$. Now you have to sum up the two probabilities. Therefore the prob. to kill the dragon is $\frac27\cdot 0.9$

Comment: @Pyckaz Because there is only one available real sword to choose from.  Using labels so I can communicate locations better, the numerator is $\binom{A}{B}\binom{C}{D}$.  The $2$ comes into play by $B+D=2$.  The fact there is only one excalibur comes into play by $A$ being one.

Comment: You could use general combinatorics to find the no. of ways in which the sword can be picked and then divide by total no. of possible ways.

Comment: @LoveInvariants No, it is the same-IMHO

Comment: Seemed like you were saying the overall probability to pick Excalibur is 1/7.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. So now we have: $$P(\text{picking Excalibur}\ \& \ a fake)=\frac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{6}{1}}{\binom{7}{2}}=\frac{2}{7}$$
And the final probability becomes: $P=\frac{9}{10} \cdot\frac{2}{7}$

Comment: @Pyckaz- Now it's correct.

Comment: Thanks! Is there something to modify to the problem so that it becomes more interesting?

Comment: You could allow the fake swords some low chance of being capable of slaying the dragon as well (*chain a binomial distribution expression to the end and don't ignore the contribution of if he picked two fake swords*).  You could then further ask what the probability that given the dragon is successfully slain that Arthur is actually holding the excalibur (*by using bayes' theorem*).  Both are common first-semester exercises that you should know how to do before continuing to another class.

Comment: @LoveInvariants off topic, but the question of two Excaliburs, the second could be the Caliburn or the Clarent.  [This mythology.stackexchange question](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/20/are-excalibur-and-caliburn-different-swords) has some good information on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach was fine and mostly correct however you made a mistake in building your expression.

In the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) we have some number of objects, $N$, some number of objects of a first type, $K$, implying the number of objects of a second type as being $N-K$, and we wish to choose $n$ objects and ask the probability of $k$ of those objects being of the first type.

The probability of this happening is $\dfrac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$

Here, there are $N=7$ swords in total.  $K=1$ of those swords are the excalibur.  The remaining $N-K=7-1=6$ of those swords are fakes.  We take $n=2$ swords and we ask for the probability that $k=1$ of the swords is the excalibur.

The probability is $\dfrac{\binom{\color{red}{1}}{1}\binom{6}{1}}{\binom{7}{2}}=\frac{2}{7}$.

Further, given that the excalibur was among the chosen swords, actually killing the dragon would only occur $\frac{9}{10}$ of the time after that making the probability of actually slaying the dragon as $\dfrac{2}{7}\times\dfrac{9}{10}$

Comment: Thank you alot! Can you please take a look at my edit?